# Use different theme on antd design token

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, themes, antd

Is there a way to get the text color of both the default and the dark theme with the design token?

I would like to be able to switch between the two, without changing theme, depending on a condition.

For example:

`if (x) return currentThemeColorPrimaryText`
`else return oppositeThemeColorPrimaryText`

So, it should return the "current theme" color primary text should be the default one with the default theme and the dark one with the dark theme. While the "opposite theme" color primary text should be the dark one with the default theme and the default one with the dark theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getDesignToken`](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#static-consume-eg-less) function. As docs says:

> Same as ConfigProvider, `getDesignToken` could also accept a config object as theme.

So in this case you can do something like this:

```
import { ThemeConfig, theme } from "antd";
const { defaultAlgorithm, darkAlgorithm, getDesignToken } = theme;

const DarkToken = getDesignToken({
  algorithm: darkAlgorithm
});
const LightToken = getDesignToken({
  algorithm: defaultAlgorithm
});

...

<div 
  style={{color: DarkToken.colorText}}
>
  dark color
</div>

<div 
  style={{color: LightToken.colorText}}
>
  light color
</div>
```

You can find a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-light-colors-without-switch-theme-fn7pn6).

Comment: Is there a way to take directly the dark and light theme that antd has as default? Withouth having to create my owns with the algorithms

Comment: You can leave `token` prop empty like the example or delete it leaving only `algorithm` prop. This is the only way to get antd's default theme. I've edited my answer